# Is easy_install handling relative links correctly? It's generating different absolute links than browsers and other tools do

Tags: python, html, hyperlink, easy-install

So I'm trying to install `Aptus` with `easy_install-2.5`

```
sente@oslo:~$ easy_install-2.5 --install-dir=code/lib/ aptus
Searching for aptus
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/aptus/
Reading http://nedbatchelder.com/code/aptus
Best match: Aptus 2.0
Downloading http://nedbatchelder.com/code/aptus/code/aptus/Aptus-2.0.tar.gz
error: Can't download http://nedbatchelder.com/code/aptus/code/aptus/Aptus-2.0.tar.gz: 404 Not Found
```

the HTML on http://nedbatchelder.com/code/aptus has:

`<a href="code/aptus/Aptus-2.0.tar.gz">Aptus-2.0.tar.gz</a>`

which, last I knew, should point to
   `http://nedbatchelder.com/code/aptus/code/aptus/Aptus-2.0.tar.gz` ...making easy_install right.

All other browsers and command line utilities convert that link to `http://nedbatchelder.com/code/aptus/Aptus-2.0.tar.gz` though.

I'm curious why easy_install is behaving differently than browsers and command-line-tools.

I know pip is preferred to easy_intsall-2.5 but it's not on this old system and at this point I'm more curious about easy_install.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you'd be right about how that URL should be interpreted.

However, that page has a [`base`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/base) tag, which changes the base used to convert relative URLs to absolute ones:

```
<base href='http://nedbatchelder.com'>
```

I assume easy_install just isn't looking for `base` tags.